# C# Task .Cancel take a lot of memory and it is not the same as .Abort in thread

Tags: c#

I have problem with `.Cancel` and `.Wait` in tasks. It takes a lot of memory and time.

Tasks:

```
using (CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    CancelEventArgs args = new CancelEventArgs(false);
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            action(args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }
    }, cancelSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);

    bool success = task.Wait(maxRuntime);
    if (!success)
    {
        cancelSource.Cancel();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In C# threading I use `.Abort` for aborting threads. Here in tasks I use `.Cancel.` But I think that `.Cancel` takes a lot of memory and time and it is not the same as `.Abort` in threads. How can I decrease memory when using

```
bool success = task.Wait(maxRuntime);
if (!success)
{
    cancelSource.Cancel();
    return false;
}
```

Threading example:

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(threadStart);

workerThread.Start();

bool finished = workerThread.Join(timeout);
if (!finished)
    workerThread.Abort();

return finished;
```

Comment: You said you "think". Did you measure the memory / time consumption of both methods?

Comment: yes i did. And i don't know why canceling tasks take so much memory. I don't know if problem is in .Wait or in .Cancel ...

Comment: I don't see you checking anywhere if the task was canceled. So it just it ignores the cancellation and runs to completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canceling a task is fundamentally different from aborting a thread.

Aborting a thread will raise a [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) in the thread you aborted. So even if the code that is executed inside the thread isn't aware of this mechanism it gets aborted.

Canceling a task on the other hand will not raise any exception. Instead, the task needs to check whether [`CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx) is `true` and then actively throw an `OperationCanceledException` exception. That means that the task will not respond to the cancellation request if the code executed by the task is not checking for `IsCancellationRequested`.
See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thx for answer. How can then i speed this process and decrease memory? Can i cancel thread immediately?

Comment: @senzacionale: Well, in the code inside your task check for `IsCancellationRequested` and act accordingly. The memory increase you noticed most likely has nothing to do with the call to `Wait` or `Cancel` but with the fact that the code is not immediately aborted, because your code inside the task is not responding to the cancel request. Please make sure you read the last link in my answer!

Comment: I read the article. So you suggest that i use IsCancellationRequested to check if is true and if is true throw an execeptuion in this method to cancel task? Am i right?

Comment: @senzacionale: Correct. That's the way to cancel a task.

Comment: can you give me example. i use bool isCanceled = cancelSource.IsCancellationRequested;
                        if (isCanceled)
                        {                            
                            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        } but i don't know if is ok... Thx

Comment: @senzacionale: My link has a fully working example. This should be all that is necessary to understand it. But your code looks good. If you don't need to do any cleanup it can be shortened to just the call to `cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`.